The default top app bar color changes after updating material version to 1.11.0
I designed my app to look like this:

But after updating the material library version from com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0 to com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0 the top app bar looks like this:

I didn't change anything other than the material version. And in the layout file, there is no MaterialToolbar or AppBarLayout. It's the default top app bar that appears if there isn't any NoActionBar in the theme.
I want the top app bar's to remain unchanged even after changing the material version.
Most of my activities use this type of top app bar. And so it would be great if you can tell me a solution that involve changes in the themes only.
I have defined my app's theme in the following way
themes.xml
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_theme_light_primary</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/md_theme_light_onPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_primaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_onPrimaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/md_theme_light_secondary</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/md_theme_light_onSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_secondaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_onSecondaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorTertiary">@color/md_theme_light_tertiary</item>
        <item name="colorOnTertiary">@color/md_theme_light_onTertiary</item>
        <item name="colorTertiaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_tertiaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnTertiaryContainer">@color/md_theme_light_onTertiaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorError">@color/md_theme_light_error</item>
        <item name="colorErrorContainer">@color/md_theme_light_errorContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnError">@color/md_theme_light_onError</item>
        <item name="colorOnErrorContainer">@color/md_theme_light_onErrorContainer</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/md_theme_light_background</item>
        <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/md_theme_light_onBackground</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/md_theme_light_surface</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/md_theme_light_onSurface</item>
        <item name="colorSurfaceVariant">@color/md_theme_light_surfaceVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurfaceVariant">@color/md_theme_light_onSurfaceVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOutline">@color/md_theme_light_outline</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurfaceInverse">@color/md_theme_light_inverseOnSurface</item>
        <item name="colorSurfaceInverse">@color/md_theme_light_inverseSurface</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryInverse">@color/md_theme_light_inversePrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <!-- Remove the ActionBar -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SplashScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/honey_dew</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar</item>
    </style>

</resources>

colors.xml
    <color name="seed">#5ACB6B</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_primary">#006E27</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_primaryContainer">#89FB94</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onPrimaryContainer">#002107</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_secondary">#516350</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onSecondary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_secondaryContainer">#D4E8D0</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onSecondaryContainer">#101F10</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_tertiary">#5E4CBD</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onTertiary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_tertiaryContainer">#E5DEFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onTertiaryContainer">#1A0063</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_error">#BA1A1A</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_errorContainer">#FFDAD6</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onError">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onErrorContainer">#410002</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_background">#FCFDF7</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onBackground">#1A1C19</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_surface">#FCFDF7</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onSurface">#1A1C19</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_surfaceVariant">#DEE5D9</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_onSurfaceVariant">#424940</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_outline">#72796F</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_inverseOnSurface">#F0F1EB</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_inverseSurface">#2F312D</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_inversePrimary">#6DDE7B</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_shadow">#000000</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_surfaceTint">#006E27</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_outlineVariant">#C2C9BD</color>
    <color name="md_theme_light_scrim">#000000</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_primary">#6DDE7B</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onPrimary">#003911</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_primaryContainer">#00531C</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onPrimaryContainer">#89FB94</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_secondary">#B9CCB5</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onSecondary">#243424</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_secondaryContainer">#3A4B39</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onSecondaryContainer">#D4E8D0</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_tertiary">#C8BFFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onTertiary">#2F138D</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_tertiaryContainer">#4632A4</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onTertiaryContainer">#E5DEFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_error">#FFB4AB</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_errorContainer">#93000A</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onError">#690005</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onErrorContainer">#FFDAD6</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_background">#1A1C19</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onBackground">#E2E3DD</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_surface">#1A1C19</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onSurface">#E2E3DD</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_surfaceVariant">#424940</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_onSurfaceVariant">#C2C9BD</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_outline">#8C9389</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_inverseOnSurface">#1A1C19</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_inverseSurface">#E2E3DD</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_inversePrimary">#006E27</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_shadow">#000000</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_surfaceTint">#6DDE7B</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_outlineVariant">#424940</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_scrim">#000000</color>

